# How to check is any radio button checked to change his forecolor

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem to use "For" statement on more than 10 radio buttons on my form.

Sample for one radio button:

```
If Form2.RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
Form2.RadioButton1.ForeColor = Color.Red
Else
Form2.RadioButton1.ForeColor = Color.Yellow
End If
```

But if I want to use this on any radiobutton on my form, I will use something like this:

```
   Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 10
        If Form2.RadioButton(i).Checked = True Then
            Form2.RadioButton(i).ForeColor = Color.Red
        Else
            Form2.RadioButton(i).ForeColor = Color.Yellow
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: may this link can help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459050/how-to-check-if-a-radiobutton-is-checked-in-a-group

Answer (score 0):

.net does not have control arrays.  iterate over the form's .controls collection and check the control type.

```
For Each tControl as Control in Me.Controls
  If tControl.GetType Is GetType(RadioButton)
    If DirectCast(tControl, RadioButton).Checked
      ' Change the control's color.
    Else
      ' Change the control's color.
    End If
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Yes this works but only when form load at the first time, but what if I want that form check all the time from the start does any radio button is checked and if it is, immediately change color on it. Something as add handler but on the form.

Comment: Then handle the CheckChanged(? possibly Click) event